# How to prove that every power of 6 ends in 6?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, number-systems, decimal-expansion

Yesterday I had the traditional math [matriculation exam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriculation_exam_(Finland)), and in it there was a question *"In what digit does the number $2016^{2016}$ end in?"* After the test The Matriculation Examination Board published a pdf in which they show how to basically solve all the problems in the test, and for the aforementioned question the solution was *"Because every power of 6 ends in 6, so does every power of 2016, and thus the last digit is 6"*. I understand everything else in that problem now, except how to actually show that every power of 6 ends in 6. From there on I know how to solve the last digit if $2016^{2016}$. So,

> how to prove that every power of 6 ends in 6?

Comment: by induction on $n$

Comment: I would first try to use the fact that $a_1 \equiv b_1 \pmod{10}$ and $a_2 \equiv b_2 \pmod{10}$ imply $a_1a_2 \equiv b_1b_2 \pmod{10}$ in a proof-by-induction context

Comment: @user265554 Please show what you know of this problem, how you found it and how you attempted to solve it. This way people won't down vote your question. You're not a new user so you should know this by now.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it.

Comment: $(10a+6)(10b + 6) = 10(10ab+6a+6b+3) +6$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use induction in order to complete the hint given by @ThePortakal.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$6^1=6$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$6^n=10k+6$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$6^{n+1}=$

$6\cdot\color{red}{6^n}=$

$6\cdot(\color{red}{10k+6})=$

$60k+36=$

$60k+30+6=$

$10(6k+3)+6$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 0):

A little hint: $6*6\bmod 10 = 6$.